# On Complete Function for LeanBack Player

Tags: html

I'm working with the LeanBack Player for delivering HTML5 playback.  The code I have thus far is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>LBP Test Page</title>
<!-- LeanBack Player - CSS Theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="css.player/leanbackPlayer.default.css" />
<!-- LeanBack Player - JS Source -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js.player/leanbackPlayer.pack.js"></script>
<!-- LeanBack Player Translation(s) (Examples) - JS Source -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js.player/leanbackPlayer.en.js"></script><!-- LeanBack Player - English Translation -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js.player/leanbackPlayer.de.js"></script><!-- LeanBack Player - German Translation -->
<script type='text/javascript' src='./jwplayer/swfobject.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='./jwplayer/jwplayer.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  LBP.options = {
    // show controls bar below video-viewport; default is "false"
controlsBelow: true,
// (delayed) hiding of LB player controls; default is "true"
hideControls: false,
// show playbackrate element in controls bar to change between "playbackRates"
// only available if supported by browser (if set to "true"); default is "false"
showPlaybackRates: true,
// if playbackrates should be extended; by default following are available
playbackRates: [0.5, 1, 1.3, 1.6, 2],
showSubtitles: true,
  }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="leanback-player-video"> 
  <!-- HTML5 Video Element -->
  <video width="640" height="360" preload="auto" autoplay controls poster="http://leanbackplayer.com/videos/poster/elephants_dream_640x360.jpg"> 
    <!-- HTML5 Video Source(s) -->
    <source src="http://d1odafv1k9dwyc.cloudfront.net/classroom/classroom_01a.mp4" type='video/mp4'; />
    <track enabled="true" kind="subtitles" label="English" srclang="en" type="text/x-srt" src="./subtitles/classroom_01a.srt"></track>
    }); </video>
  ￼ </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I need to detect when the video is completed.  How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the html5 video [tags doc](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#mediaevents)
and also [this blog..](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/everything-you-need-to-know-about-html5-video-and-audio/)

so you can add a even to it to test if the video it is ended:

```
var myVideo = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];

    myVideo.onended = function(e) {
      //do something
    }
```